# Select com PHP PDO e MySql com valores condicionais na query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho a seguinte tabela, chamada 'animal':

[image: Tabela]

E na minha aplicação com PHP utilizando PDO, preciso fazer um select com valores que são condicionais. **Por exemplo**:

O usuário vai passar como parâmetro para a busca apenas os campos 'TIPO' e 'Status' (que são obrigatórios). E a partir dai seria retornado para ele todos os animais cadastrados com os valores inseridos. Até ai tudo certo.

Meu problema começa quando o usuário resolver inserir outros parâmetros que não apenas os obrigatórios, pois preciso gerar querys novas com os campos inseridos. Gostaria de saber como fazer isso sem ter que criar uma nova query pra cada parâmetro inserido, de preferência.

Meu código atualmente está assim:

```
if(isset($_GET['status']) && isset($_GET['pet'])){
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $especie = $_GET['pet'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM animal WHERE ( TIPO = :TIPO , Status = :STATUS)";

    $stmt = $conecta->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':TIPO',$especie);
    $stmt->bindParam(':STATUS',$status);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém não consigo desenvolver a lógica para o meu problema!

Demais parametros enviados via GET pela pagina de busca:

```
$_GET['raca-dog']
$_GET['raca-cat']
$_GET['tamanho']
$_GET['cor']
$_GET['informacao']
$_GET['local']
$_GET['petPic']
```

**O que já pensei:**

- Criar um array que, se o campo estiver setado no $_GET, adiciona o valor ao fim do array e depois passar todo o array como paramtro pro select (penso que é gambiarra)
- Criar uma sequencia de condições que verifiquem os campos setados e seus valores, e pra cada campo que estiver setado criar uma nova query adicionando o valor do campo (Mais gambi ainda)

Imagem da tela de busca:

Lembrando que apenas a SITUAÇÃO e a ESPÉCIE são obrigatórios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que sintaxe é esta para a condição de sua cláusula WHERE (WHERE ( TIPO = :TIPO , Status = :STATUS))? O que significa esta ,?

Comment: é uma forma de se passar um parâmetro sem que se passe o valor diretamente, podendo atribuir o valor que quiser para esse parâmetro, como fiz em: 
$stmt->bindParam(':TIPO',$especie);
$stmt->bindParam(':STATUS',$status);

Comment: O parâmetro de busca deve, obrigatoriamente, ser selecionado pelo usuário ou ele pode digitar algo no campo de busca e retornar as tabelas em que qualquer um dos campos forem iguais a busca?

Comment: Ele pode ou não inserir os dados nos outros campos, vou atualizar a pergunta com uma imagem da tela de busca

Comment: pronto, atualizei para entenderem melhor

Comment: O que eu indaguei é que, de acordo com meu conhecimento, não existe este tipo de expressão na sintaxe definida para comando SQL. Talvez você queira utilizar um operador lógico.

Comment: é do PHP a sintaxe

Comment: Mas você está enviando a string, com um comando SQL, para ser executado em seu SGBD, não tem nada a ver com PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua sintaxe da query deveria ser `SELECT * FROM animal WHERE TIPO = :TIPO AND Status = :STATUS`

Com relação a sua lógica para as condições opcionais você começou a pensar por um caminho bom quando pensou em arrays porém terminou de forma equivocada.

Para elaborar essa lógica de de condições opcionais de forma mais simples, você vai precisar de:

1. Trocar os parâmetros da query para `?`
2. Armazenar os valores correspondentes a cada `?` para posteriormente fazermos os binds
3. Criar uma lista com os índices das condições opcionais com sua respectiva condição sql
4. Percorrer a lista das condições e verificar se existe em `$_GET` e em caso positivo decorar `$query` com essa condição e armazenar o valor na lista de binds
5. Preparar a query
6. Executar a query com os respectivos binds
7. Alterar o nome do campo onde seleciona a raça na página `html` para `raca` dessa forma não existirão `$_GET['raca-cat']` e `$_GET['raca-dog']` no arquivo `php` e será tratado somente como `$_GET['raca']` pois não há essa distinção de acordo com a estrutura do seu banco.

Veja o seu código com as etapas listadas acima

```php
// To do Tratar valores do $_GET
if(isset($_GET['status']) && isset($_GET['pet'])){

    // 1. Query básica
    $query  = sprintf(
        "SELECT * FROM animal WHERE TIPO = ? AND Status = ?%s", 
        isset($_GET['petPic']) ? ' AND IMAGEM IS NOT NULL' : ''
    );

    // 2. valores para binds na mesma sequencia que são add na query
    $binds  = [$_GET['pet'], $_GET['status']];

    // 3. Array mapeado com os indices de $_GET e
    $opcionais = [
        'raca'          => 'RACA = ?',
        'tamanho'       => 'TAMANHO = ?',
        'cor'           => 'COR = ?',
        'informacao'    => 'DESCRICAO = ?',
        'local'         => 'LOCALIZACAO = ?'
    ]

    /**
     * 4. Decorar a query com as condições opcionais
     */
    foreach ($opcionais as $option => $condition)
    {
        if (isset($_GET[$option])) 
        {
            $query = sprintf('%s AND %s', $query, $condition);
            $binds[] = $_GET[$option];
        }
    }

    // 5. prepara a query para o bind
    $stmt   = $conecta->prepare($query);

    // 6. executa a query com os binds
    $stmt->execute($binds);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, é exatamente isso que precisava. Muito obrigado mesmo!